# java heap size error for selecting 0.4 million records

Tags: java, mysql

i have 2gb ram on my computer. its a windows 7
using eclipse for java
when i run a program that runs a select query on mysql database with 0.4 million records it gives heap size error.
this is my present eclipse.ini

```
-vmargs
-Xmx1000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
```

what can i do ?

Comment: Your eclipse.ini settings are not relevant, if you run your program from inside Eclipse it's started in its own JVM. The eclipse.ini settings are only for Eclipse itself, not for your own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You're talking about your eclipse.ini? You should of course use the debug configuration to specify the arguments:

Run > Debug Configurations ... > [your configuration] > Arguments > VM Arguments

<strike>How big is one row? 1000 MB / 400,000 records = max 2,5 KB per row (it will be less as you can't use the whole heap).</strike>

(Note I used 1MB = 10^6 bytes)

It rows are small, run your application with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and analyse the resulting heap dump using [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you run the query in a plugin of Eclipse or do you use Eclipse to run a Java program? In the latter case, the settings in `eclipse.ini` aren't inherited. You must repeat the in the launch configuration of your app.

Comment: its the latter case . i am using eclipse to run java program . how to set the launch configuration of the program.

Comment: Use the "Run" menu and click on "Run Configurations...". You'll get a dialog where you can modify the options passed to your program and the options passed to the VM.